# What to check when replacing CCFL backlight inverter?

Tags: display, repair

I've got a 22'' LCD monitor with a damaged CCFL inverter. It has the inverter (4 lamps), power and controller as separate boards.

I would like to replace it with a 19'' LCD monitor part that has the power board and inverter as one module. I have tested this module very briefly with the 22'' monitor and it lights the backlight lamps.

As I have no means of measuring the output from the 19'' inverter and I can't find any specs for the 22'' screen anyway, I have no idea of what power is needed to drive the lamps.

Are most types of CCFL inverters compatible, for fixed ranges of lamp size?

Can I assume that the new inverter wont burn the lamps/my house/my city?

What specs (aside from voltage/current) should I look for when replacing an inverter?

Comment: Not to nit pick, but how can a monitor be LED if it's got a fluoro inverter in it? If you mean the led driver then provided that the leds need the same current and roughly the same voltages (you've probably got at least +/- 10% voltage margin to play with), then you may be ok, leds have constant current drivers, so as long as the driver can keep the same current flowing, and the rest of the display is happy talking to the new board, you're probably good.

Comment: I meant LCD display, thanks for pointing it out. Correcting now.

Comment: These things happen, I think those ccfl tubes run around the 1kV mark, larger ones I think do need higher voltages, but seeing as you're only going from 19" to 22" the inverter probably has some margin (the starting voltage is higher than the running voltage anyway) so the inverter likely has the capacity. Ideally you get a direct replacement (eBay maybe?) but you could always do a bench test and leave it running for a while.

Comment: I have found some very cheap "universal" inverters that I think are worth trying in the future, but I keep wondering if that "universality" is so "universal". Also, I would prefer not damaging the lamps, as replacing them would be a lot harder than just the inverter.

Comment: For the most part, your probably fine. I won't give it a second thought. But ymmv and if it breaks that's on you.

Comment: I've been burned by cheap power supplies in the past (and ccfl inverters can literally burn - 1kV will form a nice arc), but there isn't much to break in these ccfl inverters, provided they are built to appropriate voltage isolation standards, universal may be universal (see if you can find a direct replacement, then decide which path you want to go down)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recently been replacing lamps and inverters. If the lamps or anything is out of range the inverter board will shut down. Voltages are beyond the range of my meter, 1000 VAC in fact it arced internally at some point. I have been using universal inverters from ebay with no problem. The only thing to look for is 1, 2, or 4 lamps. Some have brightness controls other do not.
Typically there are 4 input connections on the inverter board. +12 volts, Ground, +5/0 volts On/Off, and a variable voltage between 0 and 5 volts for brightness.
If replacing lamps you must measure and get the correct size to fix you monitor.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of ccfl just to provide backlighting for the LCD panel. You avoid many ambiguous questions and revive the LCD display very easily if you totally rid off the ccfl and wire up strips of white led instead.

You said there are 4 ccfl tubes behind the panel. If I were you, I will stick 8 led strips cut into proper size. Easier if the strips are 12 volt type because they won't draw as much current as the 5 volt strips. Link them all and take out two feed wires for the strips from behind the panel and power it up using an external power supply.

http://m.ebay.com/itm/181904149259

The above link shows the type of led strip I'm talking about.

This strip can be cut after every three LEDs, so its easier to size it according to your panel. You may also externally control its brightness to properly match it with the optics/diffusers used in the panel.

I believe the best way to revive all ccfl lit LCD products is upgrade them with the LED strips.